# Show a Category X's custom post type on Category X archive page?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, query-posts, loop

I created a custom post type "landing_page" to hold content I want to display on the top of category archive pages.

So for each category, I have one landing_page entry tagged with that category. What do I have to add to the category archive.php template to get it to show that category's (or custom taxonomy term's) landing_page content?

```
query_posts(
    array( 'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => landing_page,
    'category' => [[???]] ));

     while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest adding something like this to the top of the theme file or wherever you want this content to appear in the archive, category or whatever..

```
// Check if it's a category or taxonomy archive
if( is_category() || is_tax() ) {
    // Grab the queried data, slug, tax, etc..
    $queried = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    // Check taxonomy and slug are set
    if( isset( $queried->taxonomy ) && isset( $queried->slug ) ) {
        // Look for a landing page post type with a slug that matches the current queried slug
        $landing_page = get_posts( 'name=' . $queried->slug . '&post_type=landing_page&posts_per_page=1&nopaging=1' );
        // If the result wasn't empty
        if( !empty( $landing_page ) ) {
            // Output the title and content using the same filters WP uses in the loop
            echo apply_filters( 'the_title', get_the_title( $landing_page->ID ) );
            echo apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content( $landing_page->ID ) );
        }
    }
}
```

This will should do what you want without interupting the main category query for the archive.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Looks good... but `get_posts` will return an array, so I think you might have to refer to `$landing_page[0]->ID` to get the title and content.

Comment: I might use new WP_Query() instead of get_posts(). I have yet to fully understand the differential efficiency/best practices surrounding WP_Query/get_posts/query_posts (even with explanatory diagrams like this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)—but my understanding is that the others involve WP_Query, so using WP_Query itself is more direct.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current category with

and since you are using archive.php and not category.php check if its a category first so something like this:

```
if (is_category()){
query_posts(
    array( 'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type' => 'landing_page',
    'category' =>  get_query_var('cat'));

     while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        the_content();
     endwhile;

}
```

Comment: Missing quotes around your post type value.. ;)